# new value is pushed into videoarr, but my html did not show the newly pushed data..what can i do to improve my codes?

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
  function createVideoList() {
  var list = "";
  var v = 0;
  $.each(videoarr, function (index, value) {
    var name = videoarr[v].name;
    var img = videoarr[v].img;
    list = list + "<div id='video'><a href='#'><img src='" + img + "' 
id='videoimg'/><h4>" + name + "</h4></a></div>"
    v = v + 1;
  });
  $('#videoresult').html(list);
}

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#videouploadpage', function () {
  $('#GetVideoInfo').on('tap', function () {

    console.log(videoarr);
  })
})
```

the new value is pushed into videoarr and it is shown in the console, but my Html did not show the newly pushed data..what can I do to improve my codes? Does anyone have a simple solution on the problems? Thank you for helping!

Comment: How are you displaying your data into HTML?

Comment: sorry..i have forgot to edit the code...yes im displaying the data in html but is not updated

Comment: I am confused. At the place where you have written `console.log(videoarr);', you need to display that in HTML. Correct? If yes, in which HTML element you want to display?

Comment: It looks like you have incomplete code. Can you bifurcate HTML and Jquery? Also, where is `videoIndex` defined?

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: So, after pushing the new item in videoarr, you are not doing anything to update your HTML.

Comment: ohh ok...i get it.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not performing any action to update the HTML after adding the new item in the array. You can probably call `createVideoList()` function after adding the new item in `videoarr`.

```js
var videoarr = [{
  name: 'Japchae: sdf (Glass noodles stir-fried with vegetables)',
  date: '4 Nov 2014',
  img: 'https://www.maangchi.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/japchae_plate.jpg',
  YoutubeId: 'i1djfV9uigc',
  FullRecipeUrl: 'https://www.maangchi.com/recipe/japchae',
  description: 'Japchae, sweet potato starch noodles stir fried with vegetables and meat, is one of Korea’s best-loved dishes, and one of the most popular on my website as well.Stir frying each ingredient separately seems like a lot of labor, but each one requires a different cooking time and a bit of care, and keeping the color and freshness of each ingredient intact makes for a stunning final presentation.'
},
{
  name: 'Hot and spicy rice cake',
  date: '30 Jan 2013',
  img: 'https://www.maangchi.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ddeokbokki_sizzlingpot.jpg',
  YoutubeId: 'TA3Uo3a9674',
  FullRecipeUrl: 'https://www.maangchi.com/recipe/tteokbokki',
  description: 'When I lived in Korea I learned the secret to making good tteokbokki from a famous place in a market. It was run by an old lady who could always be found stirring her tteokbokki. People were lined up to buy it.'
},
];
function createVideoList() {
  var list = "";
  var v = 0;
  $.each(videoarr, function (index, value) {
    var name = videoarr[v].name;
    var img = videoarr[v].img;
    list = list + "<div id='video'><a href='#'><img src='" + img + "id='videoimg'/><h4>" + name + "</h4></a></div>"
    v = v + 1;
  });
  $('#videoresult').html(list);
};
createVideoList();

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#videouploadpage', function () {
  $('#GetVideoInfo').on('tap', function () {
    var date = $('#upload_date').val();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var image = $('#image').val();
    var video = $('#video').val();
    var url = $('#url').val()
    var desc = $('#descript').val();

    videoarr.push({
      name: title,
      date: date,
      img: image,
      YoutubeId: video,
      FullRecipeUrl: url,
      description: desc
    });
    console.log(videoarr);
    createVideoList();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videoresult">df</div>
```